# what should I do to fixed the code sign exit code 65

Tags: ios, flutter, codesign

Today when I using fastlane `v2.206.2` command `bundle exec fastlane beta` to build the ios app in github actions, shows error like this:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CodeSign /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gzzbtgmsqethlzedjqlbspydxjjv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
(1 failure)
[10:45:29]: Exit status: 65
[10:45:30]:
```

I have tried to upgrade the xcode version and fastlane version, still did not fixed this. problem. why would this happen? what should I do to avoid this problem? This is the github action code snippnet:

```
  - name: Deploy to TestFlight/PGY
    run: |
      cd ./ios
      bundle exec fastlane beta
    env:
      FLUTTER_ROOT: ${{ secrets.FLUTTER_ROOT }}
      APPLE_ID: ${{ secrets.APPLE_ID }}
      GIT_URL: ${{ secrets.GIT_URL }}
      PGY_USER_KEY: ${{ secrets.PGY_USER_KEY }}
      PGY_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.PGY_API_KEY }}
      TEAM_ID: ${{ secrets.TEAM_ID }}
      ITC_TEAM_ID: ${{ secrets.ITC_TEAM_ID }}
      FASTLANE_USER: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_USER }}
      FASTLANE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_PASSWORD }}
      FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD }}
      FASTLANE_SESSION: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_SESSION }}
      MATCH_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MATCH_PASSWORD }}
      MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME: ${{ secrets.MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME }}
      MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}
      DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS: ${{ secrets.DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS }}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a known issue affecting recent versions of Fastlane running combined with Xcode 14 and/or macOS 13.

You can check open issues:

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20810

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20825

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/20800

For the time being, the only solution I found in my project is locking a lower version of Xcode in the Fastfile, eg:

```
xcode_select("/Applications/Xcode_13.4.1.app")
```

Depending on your Github runtime, you may have different versions of Xcode installed. Assuming you're on `macOS-latest` (macOS 12), [here](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/macos/macos-12-Readme.md#xcode) is a list of available Xcode versions.

Comment: Rafal did you find any new solution?

Comment: @Santiago No, we’re using this solution since then